# impossible to see log 'system.out.println' in glassfish v2

Tags: jakarta-ee, logging, system.out, glassfish-2.x

I would like to see the output : system.out.println() on 'log file' to  sun glassfish enterprise server v2.1.1. I found this on Oracle doc :

> Log Options The Administration GUI provides the following two logging
>   options:
>
> Option 1 — Log stdout (System.out.print) content to the event log
>
> Option 2 — Log stderr (System.err.print) content to the event log
>
> When these options are set, stdout and stderr messages are written to
>   the server.log file. (The event log is a syslog daemon on Solaris and
>   Event Log on Microsoft Windows.)
>
> If the above options are not set:
>
> Anything written to stdout or stderr (that is, using System.out or
>   System.err) will not appear in the logs.

But, I can't find this option. I can't see syso on consol on eclipse, so Is it possible to see output syso  when I deploy my appplication  ?

Thank you.